# How to unit test when data is coming from text box

Tags: unit-testing, xunit

I am new to writing unit test cases .
I am trying to use XUnit for testing my c# methods.

The method accepts data from 3 text boxes. 
How can I unit test this without a UI and provide the data?

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

string txt1= txtBox1.Text;
string txt2= txtBox2.Text;
string txt3= txtBox3.Text;

// this data is then manipulated and finally sent to a service

}
```

The purpose of unit test is to check if the method called on button click runs without errors.

Comment: Can you provide some code as an example?

Comment: Edited to add some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the great things about unit testing is that it addresses the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) in your code. It also points out areas that can benefit from encapsulation. One recommendation I can make is to encapsulate different portions of your code so that you can create logical separations. Below is a brief and simplistic example:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

    string txt1= txtBox1.Text;
    string txt2= txtBox2.Text;
    string txt3= txtBox3.Text;

    string data = data_manipulation(txt1, txt2, txt3);
    send_to_service(data, sender)
}

public string data_manipulation(string txt1, string txt2, string txt3){
    //manipulate data
    return manipulated_data;
}

public void send_to_service(string data, object sender){
    //send data to service
}
```

By doing so, this allows you to test your data manipulation logic without being dependant on testing the sending of data to the service as well.

Comment: Thanks I guess I will use this approach. Didn't think of this before.